# Spelling "-sed", like in analysed, for some other words

Tags: british-english, orthography

I'm writing a paper in Brithish English so I write "analy**s**ed" instead of "analy**z**ed" but there are some other words that I'm not certain what would be the appropriate spelling, mainly because these words are not commonly used...

If I write transitivi**z**ed, should I spell it with **s** or **z**?

Comment: Generally, to check spellings, you look in a dictinoary.  If you fail to find it, then, to ask such a question here, you should report the attempt to  look it up.

Comment: @GEdgar - "Generally, to check spellings, you look in a dictinoary" - never was a truer word written.

Comment: Let me try to help.  If you are using MS word, you can select English (US) or English (UK) and any word you type that does not conform will automatically be underlined with a red wavy line.  Look on-line for YouTube tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: All your porpositions I did them already, that's why I tried this way....

Comment: Don't over-analyce it!!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Note that 'British English' is a loose term. There are some people in the UK who prefer -ize spellings and some in the US who prefer the -ise variants. Be consistent. But watch out for the odd word where only one form is standard.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth, good advice...

Comment: If you want British, look in the Oxford Dictionary (hosted by Lexico) https://www.lexico.com/definition/analyse  They even give the American spelling as well.

Comment: Thanks @chaslyfromUK I'll check it...

Comment: British preference for spelling the suffix *-ise* that Americans spell *-ize* is one thing. (I think Fowler proposed that the *-ize* version should be used only where an underlying Greek original terminates in -ίζειν.) But the words analy[s/z]e, paraly[s/z]e,and cataly[s/z]e are not etymologically analogous; instead, they incorporate -λυσ- *(-lys-),* the aorist stem of the verb λύειν, *to break, destroy* (or *liberate).* That is why, contrary to popular belief and jokes, *analyze* (as we Yanks tend to spell it, thanks to that false analogy) does *not* mean to render something more anal.